# upload image without submit not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function upload_img(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#preview_image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

<input type="file" id="image" onchange="upload_img(this);"/>
<img id="preview_image">
```

I have a function can preview the image from user upload without submit.

it works fine in all browser but safari, anyone know where is the problems?

Comment: Please check Safari version and see if it is supported. http://caniuse.com/filereader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
if(window.FileReader) {   //do this
    } else {
       //the browser doesn't support the FileReader Object, so do this
    }
```

Comment: what if it not support fileReader, any other way to solve this?

Comment: window.FileReader support in Safari.. So do your code in if condition and for other browser do your code in else condition.